# How do you add a draggable input in css?

Tags: css

So essentially, I'm quite a beginner web designer. I've only just started. My question is, how does one make it so that there is a field in which you can drag something? As in, how do you make it so that a certain field responds to something being dragged into it? My situation is I'm making a website with photos. I'd like to make it so that one can drag the photos into their "gallery" which will then enable them to download it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps this is not the right platform to ask such broader questions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is basically a input of type `file`

```
<div style={{ borderRadius: '5px', height: '220px', textAlign: 'center', border: '1px solid #E4E7EE', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', textAlign: 'center' }} >
  <div style={{ margin: 20, borderRadius: '5px', height: '100%', textAlign: 'center', border: '1px solid #E4E7EE', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', textAlign: 'center', borderStyle: 'dashed' }}>
    <input
       style={{
         position: 'relative', opacity: '0', textAlign: 'center', zIndex: '1', height: '100%',
       }}
       type="file"
       accept="image/*"
       onChange={this.uploadImageFile}
    />
  <div style={{ color: '#4B5D71', fontSize: '14', margin: '20% 15%', position: 'absolute', textAlign: 'center' }}>
     Drag or browse the watermark file to upload.
  </div>
```

This will create an input of type file which is hidden inside a rectangular area, where you can click and open the file manager or drag and drop inside it.